# Do any powers use the percentile dice anymore?

Tags: dnd-4e, dice

The "percentile", or "10d10" dice are still found as a standard component of most polyhedral dice sets.  But, I've yet to see use of them in my (albeit limited) experience with D&D 4e.  Are there powers or other rules I'm not aware of, that still use these?

Comment: I've never seen the 'tens' d10 called a 10d10 (cuz that means roll 10 ten-sided dice and sum them). 

I realize you mean a regular d10 plus a d10 labeled 00, 10, 20, 30, ... 90.

Comment: I've seen it written as **d%**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, not in the WotC books, anyhow. It's possible that someone slipped a percentile dice requirement into a third party supplement, but there aren't even tables that use percentile dice in WotC's stuff. The new red box Starter Set comes with six dice -- no d10 with extra 0s after the digits to serve as the 10s digit.

Comment: Sadly I can't use my nifty nested percentile die now.

Comment: @C. Ross: Nested percentile die?

Comment: Koplow Double Dice! Check it: http://www.koplowgames.com/page31.html

Comment: Those are totally geektastic!

Comment: Somehow I hadn't realized that.  It's kind of sad, although I suppose Platonic solids purists are happy.

Comment: :-( I'm gonna miss d100.

Answer (score 6):

The [Official Dungeons And Dragons Dice Set](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/244690000) only comes with 1d10, so... I think that's a pretty good sign that it's officially depreciated from use.

Answer (score 5):

I played the new [Gamma World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_World) 7th ed.(at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786955082)) as a one-shot this weekend and **I had to roll percentile dice** for the first time in a *very* long time, possibly since 2nd ed. Gamma World is based on D&D 4e, but quite scaled back (no healing surges, no daily powers, no bull rush) and [a little weird](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20100927). From [WotC](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/254600000):

> The D&D Gamma World Roleplaying Game offers hours of rollicking entertainment in a savage land of adventure, where the survivors of some mythical future disaster must contend with radioactive wastes, ravaged cities, and rampant lawlessness. Against a nuclear backdrop, heroic scavengers search crumbled ruins for lost artifacts while battling mutants and other perils....[Gamma Wold] is a complete, stand-alone roleplaying game that uses the 4th Edition D&D Roleplaying Game system as its foundation.

The percentile rolls were part of rolling for my equipment during character creation. I rolled a '1' on the random equipment table which meant "roll twice on the `Ancient Junk` table" and the `Ancient Junk` table needed a percentile roll. So I rolled a 70 and a 12 and acquired:

- 12 - a twenty pound dumb-bell
- 70 - a gas grill (with a tank of propane)

I wound up playing an 8' tall stuffed teddy bear that threw the dumb-bell as its heavy two-handed ranged weapon and gave bear hugs to bad things. I had a blast. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The explanation of "Game Dice" on p8 of the PH includes the following,

> You can use d10s to roll percentages,
>   if you ever need to. Roll 1d10 for the
>   “tens” and 1d10 for the “ones” to
>   generate a number between 1 and 100.
>   Two 10s is 100, but otherwise a 10 on
>   the tens die counts as 0—so a 10 on
>   the tens die and a 7 on the ones die
>   is a result of 7 (not 107!).

I'm still searching for an example of where they are needed though!  Good question :)

Answer (score 2):

I still use them behind the screen for a lot of things but nothing that I can think of in front of my players.  In the few cases were I might want to represent a random effect, I can "round" the odds to fit within one of the standard dice types.

Answer (score 1):

Not an official use, but our DM rolls percentage dies on all critical failures(PC and monster, weapon and skill checks). If he rolls a 90+ you get to reroll the die. 10% and below something bad happens. It adds a bit of randomness...and gives the percentage die some love as they do often feel neglected.